# get expires_at for current user

Tags: php, laravel-8

I can with `\Auth::id()` get user_id or with `Auth::user()` can user class.

How can get value `oauth_access_tokens.expires_at` for current user( for example  `Auth::user()->accessToken->expires_at`).

I search but can not find any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this method for get expires_at from Auth

`getProtectedValue(\Auth::user()->token(),"attributes")["expires_at"]`